# Possible application of Lyapunov stability theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $F: U \times \mathbb{R}^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$F(u, v) = (v, -\nabla P(u))$$
where $P: U \subset  \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$.

Show that:   a singularity $(x_0, 0)$ of $w' = F(w)$ (thats it $F(x_0, 0) = 0$) is stable if $x_0$ is a strict local minimum point  of $P$.

I am trying to solve this using Lyapunov stability theorem, but I can not figure it out any Lyapunov function.

@Edit I am trying to show that
$$L: V \times \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$$ given by
$L(u, v)=P(u)-P(x_0)+||v||^2$, is a Lyapunov function. Here $V$ is such that $P(x_0) < P(x) \forall x \in V$.

I am tring to show that $dL_{(u,v)}(F(u,v)) \leq 0$. I found
$$dL_{(u,v)}(F(u,v)) = \nabla P(u)v-2v\nabla P(u)$$ And this is where I got stuck.

Comment: Please, share with us your efforts. Otherwise no one will help you.

Comment: Try with the energy function $L=\frac12\|v\|^2+(P(u)-P(x_0))$ and use that the scalar product is symmetric.